# Which one is the best strategy for created_at and updated_at columns

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Which one is the best strategy for created_at and updated_at columns on Rails?

Datetime or Timespan? NULL or NOT NULL? DEFAULTS?

I try to googling some about this but I found nothing.

Comment: Why not use `t.timestamps` and rails defaults?

Comment: quoting the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)  "the two columns are automatically managed by Rails Active Record .."

Answer (score 0):

You've kinda answered your own question, though I think to some extent this is opinion based and not a good fit for SO..

created/updated "at", is a point in time, not a range of time.. hence it should be a datetime, not a timespan

Whether or not you null the updatedat with a new row, or set it the same as createdat, is a decision for you alone. Most of the time I see it set to a value, as it removes the headache of dealing with nulls

Createdat can be defaulted to the database server clock time, unless you really need it done in the front end; it's easy to do as part of a table def, can be overridden by the front end if needed, but ensures that setting it is not forgotten by a front end oversight